# Finding a weighting function

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I have this equation: $$(1+x)y''-xy'-y = 2x.$$
I have to bring this equation to the self-adjoint form. I have already solved this step with using integration factor method and I obtained,
\begin{equation}
[(x+1)e^{-x}y']'-e^{-x}y = 2x(x+1)e^{-x}
\end{equation}
but my problem is that from here I don't know how can i find the $p(x),\rho(x)$ and $q(x)$ from the self-adjoint form so that i can then solve the differential equation using Lagrange? so all i need is to know how can i extract them from the self-adjoint equation found.
Thanks in advance.